# No inserta consulta sql con php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

(adjunto todo el codigo en donde radica el problema,solo lo necesario)

**Problema**: cuando realizo la sentencia INSERT no me crea un producto en la tabla_productos,por lo general antes funcionaba bien el sistema de tienda en linea,desde que lo volvi a trabajar le he arreglado pequeños errores pero normalmente creaba sus productos (consultas sql con PDO) de forma correcta,ya depure el codigo,probe varias cosas como:

1. Quitar-poner default,quitar-poner null..etc
2. Como las consultas son con pdo a veces inserto `NULL` y asi estando para recibir nulo en la BD,a veces probe mandar campo vacio asi ..   '', tambien enviando valor 0 entre comillas y sin comillas
3. Por lo general no pude arreglar el xamp por mas que trate no arrancan servicios apache en ningun puerto
4. Tengo un servidor web de pago (no lo he vuelto a pagar,no hay dominio) entonces no puedo probar hay,probe en servidor web gratuito..
5. Actualmente uso wamp
6. Migre todas las tablas a engine myisam
7. Se supone que lo tengo bien configurado para capturar errores de consultas,PDO_attr_err_mode y pues todo lo demas que imaginen
8. Ningun navegador me muestra ningun error,ni chrome ni firefox,con extensiones y sin extensiones,borrando cache y nada.
9. `Error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);` y sin embargo no muestra nada

-pues la verdad que asi queda imposible saber que sucede y ya no se entonces que mas hacer

```
<!-- language: lang-php-->
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

<?php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_settings");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row){
    $row['ValorDolarUS'];
}

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['form1'])) {
    $valid = 1;

    if(empty($_POST['tcat_id'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= "You must have to select a top level category<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['mcat_id'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= "You must have to select a mid level category<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['ecat_id'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= "You must have to select an end level category<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['p_name'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= "Product name can not be empty<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['p_current_price'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= "Current Price can not be empty<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['p_qty'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= "Quantity can not be empty<br>";
    }

    $path = $_FILES['p_featured_photo']['name'];
    $path_tmp = $_FILES['p_featured_photo']['tmp_name'];

    if($path!='') {
        $ext = pathinfo( $path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $file_name = basename( $path, '.' . $ext );
        if( $ext!='jpg' && $ext!='png' && $ext!='jpeg' && $ext!='gif' ) {
            $valid = 0;
            $error_message .= 'You must have to upload jpg, jpeg, gif or png file<br>';
        }
    } else {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= 'You must have to select a featured photo<br>';
    }


    if($valid == 1) {

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl_product'");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $ai_id=$row[10];
        }

        if( isset($_FILES['photo']["name"]) && isset($_FILES['photo']["tmp_name"]) )
        {
            $photo = array();
            $photo = $_FILES['photo']["name"];
            $photo = array_values(array_filter($photo));

            $photo_temp = array();
            $photo_temp = $_FILES['photo']["tmp_name"];
            $photo_temp = array_values(array_filter($photo_temp));

            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl_product_photo'");
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            foreach($result as $row) {
                $next_id1=$row[10];
            }
            $z = $next_id1;

            $m=0;
            for($i=0;$i<count($photo);$i++)
            {
                $my_ext1 = pathinfo( $photo[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                if( $my_ext1=='jpg' || $my_ext1=='png' || $my_ext1=='jpeg' || $my_ext1=='gif' ) {
                    $final_name1[$m] = $z.'.'.$my_ext1;
                    move_uploaded_file($photo_temp[$i],"../assets/uploads/product_photos/".$final_name1[$m]);
                     copy($photo_temp[$i],"../assets/uploads/product_photos/".$final_name1[$m]);
                    $m++;
                    $z++;
                }
            }

            if(isset($final_name1)) {
                for($i=0;$i<count($final_name1);$i++)
                {
                    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_product_photo (photo,p_id) VALUES (?,?)");
                    $statement->execute(array($final_name1[$i],$ai_id));
                }
            }            
        }

        $final_name = 'product-featured-'.$ai_id.'.'.$ext;
        move_uploaded_file( $path_tmp, '../assets/uploads/'.$final_name );
        //copy( $path_tmp, '../assets/uploads/'.$final_name );

        //$OldPriceConvertToDolar = ($_POST['p_old_price'] / 3607);
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_settings");
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row){
            $row['ValorDolarUS'];
        }
        
        $ValorDolarUS = $row['ValorDolarUS'];
        
        $CurrentPriceConvertToDolar = ($_POST['p_current_price'] / $ValorDolarUS);
        
        ## AQUI RADICA EL PROBLEMA ##
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_product(
                                        p_name,
                                        p_old_price,
                                        p_current_price,
                                        p_qty,
                                        p_featured_photo,
                                        p_description,
                                        p_short_description,
                                        p_feature,
                                        p_condition,
                                        p_return_policy,
                                        p_total_view,
                                        p_is_active,
                                        ecat_id,
                                        ValorDolarUS
                                    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $statement->execute(array(
                                        $_POST['p_name'],
                                        'NULL',
                                        $CurrentPriceConvertToDolar,
                                        $_POST['p_qty'],
                                        $final_name,
                                        $_POST['p_description'],
                                        $_POST['p_short_description'],
                                        $_POST['p_feature'],
                                        $_POST['p_condition'],
                                        $_POST['p_return_policy'],
                                        0,
                                        '1',
                                        $_POST['ecat_id'],
                                        $ValorDolarUS
                                    ));
        
        /* SEGUND METODO FUNCIONANDO 100% */    
        
        // --> importante agregar la segunda conexion para query distinta <-- //
        include 'inc/conexion.php';

        //se actualiza tambien la tabla tbl_settings al tiempo para actualizar el valor del dolar
        
        /* NO ES NECESARIO ACTUALIZAT TBL_SETTINGS, ESTA TABLA TRAE POR DEFECTO UN VALOR QUE SE ACTUALIZA CONSTANTEMENTE CUANDO EL USUARIO MODIFICA EL VALOR DEL DOLAR POR SI MISMO,LA TBL_SETTINGS ES QUIEN SE ENCARGA DE ACTUALIZAR TODAS LAS DEMAS TABLAS INVOLUCRADAS DE TRAER EL VALOR DEL DOLAR */
        
        //$sql_update_tbl_settings = "UPDATE tbl_settings SET ValorDolarUS='$ValorDolarUS'";
        
        //$Result_update_tbl_settings = $Conexion -> query($sql_update_tbl_settings);       

        if(isset($_POST['size'])) {
            foreach($_POST['size'] as $value) {
                $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_product_size (size_id,p_id) VALUES (?,?)");
                $statement->execute(array($value,$ai_id));
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['color'])) {
            foreach($_POST['color'] as $value) {
                $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_product_color (color_id,p_id) VALUES (?,?)");
                $statement->execute(array($value,$ai_id));
            }
        }
    
        $success_message = 'Product is added successfully.';
    }
}
?>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Haz intentado meter la consulta en un try -  catch para revisar si esta habiendo algun tipo de problema en la BD?

Comment: @JulioGuerrero hay un archibo config.php en donde esta includo el try catch,pero he buscado que me muestre errores y no lo hace,entonces asi me queda imposible

Comment: Como tienes implementado ese archivo config.php? y haz intendado en poner la instruccion en crudo sin importar el config.php?